# For-loop variable violates loop bound

Tags: delphi, for-loop

Today I have met very strange bug.

I have the next code:

```
var i: integer;
...
for i := 0 to FileNames.Count - 1 do
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(i) + ' from ' + IntToStr(FileNames.Count - 1));
  FileName := FileNames[i];
  ...
end; 
ShowMessage('all');
```

FileNames list has one element. So, I consider then loop will be executed once and I see

```
0 from 0
all
```

It is a thing I did thousands times :).
But in this case I see the second loop iteration *when code optimization is switched on*.

```
0 from 0
1 from 0
all
```

Without code optimization loop iterates right.
For the moment I don't know even the direction to move with this issue (and upper loop bound stays unchanged, yes).

So any suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks.

I use Delphi 2005 (Upd2) compiler.

Comment: D2005 has not the best reputation. Try using a for-in loop if that works better. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33050

Comment: Please edit to provide a complete, compilable test application that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Indeed, what type is `FileNames`? How are we supposed to really believe it only has one item without seeing the proof in an example?

Comment: Please show a complete program that demonstrates the issue. Make this a simple console program that uses Writeln and not ShowMessage. Once you have done this we'll be able to investigate.

Comment: @Downvoter, I really don't believe in downvoting a new user's first question. I think the question is fine, just needs to be elaborated upon a bit more.

Comment: All `for` loop bugs I've seen before turned out to be a programmer bugs, not a compiler bugs.

Comment: @Jerry I believe in voting on the content of the question rather than empathy with the asker. Should the asker fix the question I will vote up with enthusiasm.

Comment: @user246408, see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=23849. Reported for D2005 and resolved by cannot reproduce in D2006.

Comment: Thanks for the questions and advices. Tomorrrow I'll try to make test project, if it will be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Me too, fwiw! HNY to all.

Comment: @Jerry: While I didn't downvote, your stance that a new user should be immune from downvotes is misplaced. New users have the same responsibilities as anyone else here (to understand this site and its quality standards), which is pointed out in the [tour] and [help]. Voting should be done on the quality of the post, not the experience of the user who wrote it; it's not the new user's personal history that's going to be useful (or not) in a search result by future users here.

Comment: @KenWhite True, I don't mean "immune" from it, but I don't find this question that bad, other than the sample code not being very complete. Obviously there are tons of terrible questions by new users. I see a good effort in this question. At least there was sample code.

Comment: @Jerry: Which is why (as I mentioned) I didn't downvote it. It does show some effort, and if it included the code that allowed us to repro the problem I certainly would have upvoted it.

Comment: This is not the only big bug you're going to encounter if you stick to Delphi 2005. It was an awful release, and was never really fixed - it should have never been sold. Delphi 2006 was slightly better, but it has many bugs too. Delphi 2007 is the last non-Unicode release with somewhat acceptable quality.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but have you considered writing `ShowMessage(IntToStr(i + 1) + ' from ' + IntToStr(FileNames.Count));` instead of `ShowMessage(IntToStr(i) + ' from ' + IntToStr(FileNames.Count - 1));`? I mean it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @JerryDodge What OP eventually discovered as the problem shows that the question failed to provide _any_ of the actually relevant information. This is why the question is poor quality and should probably be closed (at least in its current form). As for downvoting, I would ordinarily dv a question like this. However, I'm not "trigger-happy" and will usually give the asker time to review comments and fix the question first.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the QC report referred to by LU RD, and my own experience with D2005, here is a few workarounds. I recall using the while loop solution myself.

1.Rewrite the for loop as a while loop

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  while i < FileNames.Count do
  begin
    ...
    inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

2.Leave the for loop control variable alone from any other processing and use a separate variable, that you increment in the loop, for string manipulation and FileNames indexing.

```
var
  ctrl, indx: integer;
begin
  indx := 0;
  for ctrl := 0 to FileNames.Count-1 do
  begin
    // use indx for string manipulation and FileNames indx
    inc(indx);
  end;
end;
```

3.You hinted at a workaround in saying `Without code optimization loop iterates right.`
Assuming you have optimization on turn it off ( {$O-} ) before the procedure/function and on ( {$O+} ) again after. Note! The Optimization directive can only be used around at least whole procedures/functions.

Comment: While technically this may work, I would never consider it an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Jerry Considering the QC report referred to by LU RD, what is an appropriate solution? Upgrading to D2006 or later? Yes. Would any workaround (an other one could be rewriting with a separate variable for the string manipulation and indexing) staying in D2005 be inappropriate?

Comment: Plus 1.  I think the d/v from wherever is a bit harsh, considering that you (as usual) are only trying to help and Borland/Emb have never been entirely forthcoming about what "Optimisation" actually means in terms of Delphi/OP codegen beyond asserting that it will not change the semantics of the generated code (some joke!).

Comment: I was just explaining why someone may have chosen to downvote your answer.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for the support. Jerry Thanks for the comment. I really don't care who dv, but the reason is important, how can one otherwise improve.

Comment: @Martyn: I didn't vote (either way) on this question, but you can clearly see the optimizations the compiler does with any loop using the CPU window and comparing the ASM code generated.

Comment: Optimisation doesn't address the real problem which is that the stack is being corrupted. I cannot understand any upvotes here, let alone 4.

Comment: @David What if stack is being corrupted as a consequence of optimization?

Comment: @TomBrunberg It won't be. It will be that call to the DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have no idea what could cause the loop to go wrong, but there are other QC reports regarding loop issues in D2005. See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11193 where a call to an inlined procedure breaks the loop index. I don't have D2005 installed, but if someone has, perhaps this can give a clue to what is going on.

Comment: @LURD I have D2005 in a 'retired' XP. I will look tomorrow if I get it fired up for some investigation.

Comment: I got my D2005 (9.0.1935.22056 Update 3) up and running and made some tests.
Miamys code in the original post doesn't fail, neither with or without optimisation, but I understand now that it was incomplete mockup code. His problem was in a .dll. I also checked the two QC entries, that LU RD brought up, and they both fail as reported by their posters in QC. Unfortunately, D2005 doesn't support copying the CPU view, but I took snapshots of the disassembly if somebody is interested. As a conclusion, it is not entirely far fetched to suspect a compiler fault if a for loop behaves wrong in D2005.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems to me I solved the problem and can explain it.
Unfortunately, I cannot make test to reproduce the bug, and I cannot show the real code, which under NDA. So I must use simplified example again.

Problem is in dll, which used in my code. Consider the next data structure:

```
type
  TData = packed record
    Count: integer;
  end;
  TPData = ^TData;
```

and function, which defined in dll:

```
Calc: function(Data: TPData): integer; stdcall;
```

In my code I try to proceed data records which are taken from list (TList):

```
var
  i: integer;
  Data: TData;
begin
  for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Data := TPData(List[i])^;
    Calc(@Data);
  end;
```

and in case when optimization is on I see second iteration in loop from 0 to 0.
If rewrite code as

```
var
  i: integer;
  Data, Data2: TData;
begin
  for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Data := TPData(List[i])^;
    Data2 := TPData(List[i])^;
    Calc(@Data2);
  end;
```

all works as expected.

Dll itself was developed by another programmer, so I asked him to take care about it.

What was unexpected for me - that local procedure's stack can be corruped in so unusual way without access violations or other similar errors. BTW, Data and Data2 variables contains correct values.

Maybe, my experience will be useful to someone. Thanks all who helps me and please sorry my unconscious mistakes.

Comment: Expecting Access Violations to prevent corrupting of local stack is a misunderstanding of what they are and how they work. Within the context of your program, you have access to all memory allocated to the program. An access violation tells you your program is trying to access memory not allowed by **any part** of your program. Basically, an AV tells you that an attempted "illegal memory operatin" has been _detected_. But it's possible to perform many illegal memory opertaion _without detection_. (Which is why you should count yourself lucky to get an AV.)

Comment: In other words, there is nothing wrong with the compiler, but the call to `Calc`  is corrupting the stack